# how I can use frequencies of elements of tuples from another table?

Tags: pyspark

I have a complicated question. I have the following column which is a pair of tuples and the other column is their frequencies.

```
Col1         Col2
('A','B')      5
('C','C')      4
('F','D')      8
```

I also have the other column which is the frequency of element of tuples and their frequency:

```
Col3         Col4
'A'          2
'B'           5
'C'           1
'F'          2
'D'           3
```

I need to make a new column from frequencies. For each tuple `(A,B)` I need to have frequancy of `A` , frequancy of `B` and frequancy of the tuple.

out put:

```
Col1       new_col
('A','B')      2,5,5
('C','C')      1,1,4
('F','D')      2,3,8
```

Comment: what is your schema ? can you do a `df.printSchema()` ?

Comment: I made data by hand

Comment: then explain your data structure pls. Depending on the structures, the functions are differents. Tuples do not exist in pyspark.

Comment: `Col1`: `new_col: array (nullable = true)`                `Col3:  string (nullable = true)`

Comment: `Col4: count: long (nullable = false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## creation of the data based on your example

### dataset 1:

```py
b = "Col1 Col2".split()
a = [
    (["A", "B"], 5),
    (["C", "C"], 4),
    (["F", "D"], 8),
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)
df1.show()
+------+----+                                                                   
|  Col1|Col2|
+------+----+
|[A, B]|   5|
|[C, C]|   4|
|[F, D]|   8|
+------+----+
```

### dataset 2 :

```py
b = "Col3 Col4".split()
a = [
    ["A", 2],
    ["B", 5],
    ["C", 1],
    ["F", 2],
    ["D", 3],
]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)
df2.show()
+----+----+
|Col3|Col4|
+----+----+
|   A|   2|
|   B|   5|
|   C|   1|
|   F|   2|
|   D|   3|
+----+----+
```

## preparation of df1

```py
df1 = df1.withColumn("value1", df1["col1"].getItem(0)).withColumn(
    "value2", df1["col1"].getItem(1)
)
df1.show()
+------+----+------+------+                                                     
|  Col1|Col2|value1|value2|
+------+----+------+------+
|[A, B]|   5|     A|     B|
|[C, C]|   4|     C|     C|
|[F, D]|   8|     F|     D|
+------+----+------+------+
```

## join of the dataframes

```py
df3 = (
    df1.join(
        df2.alias("value1"), on=F.col("value1") == F.col("value1.col3"), how="left"
    )
    .join(df2.alias("value2"), on=F.col("value2") == F.col("value2.col3"), how="left")
    .select(
        "col1",
        "value1.col4",
        "value2.col4",
        "col2",
    )
)

df3.show()
+------+----+----+----+
|  col1|col4|col4|col2|
+------+----+----+----+
|[A, B]|   2|   5|   5|
|[F, D]|   2|   3|   8|
|[C, C]|   1|   1|   4|
+------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: preparation df1 give me this error: `AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) new_col#25496 missing from new#25549,count#30689L in operator !Project [new#25549, count#30689L, new_col#25496[0] AS value1#31073].;`

Comment: @user15649753 if you use your own code to create df1, then you need to adapt. My code is working on its own. There is no count column in my example, I don't know what you did.

Comment: right your code is working on a fine data. I think the problem is for some data points the tuple has a problem. for example it is missing the second item like `('A')`. Do you know how I can remove these problematic tuple?

Comment: @user15649753 if you're use case is more complexe, you should write a proper example, not some oversimplified lines. Search on SO how to make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I don't know how to find these problematic tuples. there are a few of them. like maybe 10 out of million data points.

Comment: @user15649753 you can use [`size`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) and filter for size lower than 1

Comment: I posted a question but didn't get any answer. Do you this that is hard to do in pyspark? I know its more than easy in pandas. just get value of each rows and sort them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69636495/how-to-sort-each-row-of-a-dataframe