# how to sort each row of a dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I have a column that elements are list. How I can sort this list in alphabetic order?

```
col
["R Programming Language", "Computer Programming"]
["R Programming Language", "Working Under Pressure"]
["Master Data Management", "Entity Relationship Models"]
["Master Data Management", "Statistical Analysis Software"]
```

output:

```
col_order
["Computer Programming","R Programming Language"]
["R Programming Language", "Working Under Pressure"]
[ "Entity Relationship Models","Master Data Management"]
["Master Data Management", "Statistical Analysis Software"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_sort`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('col', F.array_sort('col')).show(10, False)

# Output
# +-------------------------------------------------------+
# |col                                                    |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+
# |[Computer Programming, R Programming Language]         |
# |[R Programming Language, Working Under Pressure]       |
# |[Entity Relationship Models, Master Data Management]   |
# |[Master Data Management, Statistical Analysis Software]|
# +-------------------------------------------------------+
```